# Unable to set name(character array) using structure in c

Tags: c, struct

```
struct Student {
char name[10];
};


void set(struct student *s,const char *n)
{
s->name=n;    // this line is showing error(incompatible types in assignment)
}


int main()
{
struct Student stud;
char name[]="abc";
set(&stud,name);
}
```

this line

```
s->name=n;
```

is showing compile time error of incompatible assignment.
how can I assign the name passed using function to the structure variable.

Comment: `student`  -->  `Student`

Comment: @haccks actually the function declaration cannot be changed it is fixed, we can only define it.

Comment: @ArunA.S how would this statement assign the name .student --> Student

Comment: no I meant change `student` to `Student`. Read my answer for the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `strcpy` to copy strings, so do

```
strcpy(s->name,n);
```

And change

```
void set(struct student *s,const char *n)
```

to

```
void set(struct Student *s,const char *n)
                ^
                capital S
```

Answer (score 2):

`s->name` is an array and it can't be a left operand of `=`. Use `strcpy` instead.